# g++ makefile "was not declared in this scope" for elements inside winbase.h

Tags: c++, c, windows, compilation, makefile

I'm trying to compile a program, which includes windows.h, but I get errors such as "error: 'DCB' was not declared in this scope" for every element that resides in winbase.h. I've included MinGW path to the needed header (also tried adding -I"C:\MinGW\x86_64-w64-mingw32\include" -lwindows to the CFLAGS variable). Suggestions?

```
# Command variables
CC = g++
DEBUG = -Wall -g
CFLAGS = -m64 -I"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\include" $(DEBUG) -c
LFLAGS = -m64 -Wl,--add-stdcall-alias -shared $(DEBUG)
COMP_CMD = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $<
LINK_CMD = $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $? -o $@
HEAD_STUB_CMD = javah -classpath $(CLASS_PATH) $*


# Path variables
CLASS_PATH = ../bin

INCL_PATH = ../include/
SRC_PATH = ../source/

SUB2 = libsercom/

INCL_PATH2 = $(INCL_PATH)$(SUB2)
SRC_PATH2 = $(SRC_PATH)$(SUB2)

# Define a virtual path for .class in the bin directory
vpath %.class $(CLASS_PATH)


all: sercom.dll


#sercom
SERCOM = sercom
$(SERCOM).dll: $(SERCOM).o
    $(LINK_CMD)

$(SERCOM).o : $(SRC_PATH2)win$(SERCOM).c $(INCL_PATH2)$(SERCOM).h $(INCL_PATH2)err$(SERCOM).h
    $(COMP_CMD)


clean :
    \rm *.o *.dll *.h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you open the header and look through the names listed in your error list. Chances are that they are wrapped with preprocessor directives there. If they do, try passing required defines in CFLAGS.

UPD: for example

#if (_WIN32_WINNT >= 0x0500)

WINBASEAPI BOOL WINAPI GetVolumePathNameA(LPCSTR,LPSTR,DWORD);

As you can see, this will require a define.

Comment: Yes I've just figured that out. I have:
#ifdef _WINDOWS
#include <windows.h>
#endif
So I changed "all" to: all: sercom.dll -D_WINDOWS
Then i get a series of errors like: error: "function '...' definition is marked dllimport"

I also have:
#ifdef LIBSERCOM_EXPORTS
#define SERCOM_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SERCOM_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

So I added:
all: sercom.dll -D_WINDOWS -DLIBSERCOM_EXPORTS

But it didn't help.

Comment: Do the errors you listed above come from winbase header now, or from somewhere else?

Comment: Ok my bad, I had to define preprocessor directives inside CFLAGS variable. Since you posted the soultion, although I fugured it out by myself just after I've posted it, I'll accept your answer.